# Testing angularjs modules with mocha in node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocha.js

mymodule.js is defined as:

```
angular.module('mymodule', []).factory('MyModule', function () { /* my code */ });
```

I then have a mocha test script (test.js) like:

```
var chai = require('chai');
chai.use(require("chai-as-promised"));
var angular = require('angular');
require('mymodule.js');
```

When running test.js with mocha I get an error saying that angular is not defined.

I've instead tried to use angular.injector like:

```
var angular = require('angular');
var injector = angular.injector(['mymodule']);
var mymodule = injector.get('MyModule');
```

but then I get the error "Failed to instantiate module" as mymodule.js hasn't been loaded.

Is there a simple way to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `var angular = ...` in test.js to `global.angular = ...`

**Explanation**

Since mymodule.js is in a different scope than test.js, declaring `angular` as a `var` within test.js will not make it accessible within mymodule.js.  You must attach it to the global object to make it available anywhere without requiring it.

See http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global